# Binding multiple span tags with Knockout inside a container only rendering the first element

Tags: knockout.js

Given this knockout javascript:

```
function TestModel(data) {
    this.Id = ko.observable(data.Id);
    this.Name = ko.observable(data.Name);
}

function TestView() {

    this.TestList= ko.observableArray([]);  

    this.TestList([{Id: 1, Name: 'One'},{Id: 2, Name: 'Two'}]);
}

ko.applyBindings(new TestView());
```

And this Html:

```
<div data-bind='foreach: TestList'>
    <p>
        <span data-bind="text: Id" />
        <span data-bind="text: Name" />
    </p>
</div>
```

I would expect it to render like this:

```
<div>
    <p>
        <span>1</span>
        <span>One</span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <span>2</span>
        <span>Two</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

But instead it looks like this:

```
<div>
    <p>
        <span>1</span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <span>2</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

If I change the Html so that each `span` is in it's own `p` tag, it does render them both.

```
<div data-bind='foreach: TestList'>
    <p>
        <span data-bind="text: Id" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <span data-bind="text: Name" />
    </p>
</div>
```

Also, if I drop the span tags and use the comment syntax it renders both bindings just fine:

```
<div data-bind='foreach: TestList'>
    <p>
        <!--ko text: Id--><!--/ko-->
        <!--ko text: Name--><!--/ko-->
    </p>
</div>
```

**Why is the second `span` tag not rendering in the first example?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change this:

```
<span data-bind="text: Id" />
```

To this:

```
<span data-bind="text: Id"></span>
```

In my experience, KO doesn't like it when you don't have a closing tag.

Comment: I knew it had to be something silly. That cleared it right up.