# Applying click binding to element created after applybindings

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, typescript

I have an element that's being created after applyBindings is called.

```
<span data-bind="html: $root.someObservable() && $root.generateLink()" />
```

where someObservable is an observable that gets set to true AFTER applybindings has been called, and the function, which is located in the view model:

```
function generateLink() {
    var d = document.createElement("div");
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href = "someurl.com";
    link.target = "_blank";
    link.textContent = "link";
    d.appendChild(link);

    return d.innerHTML;
}
```

I have confirmed that the function is called after applyBindings is called. I am trying to apply a click binding to this element. None of the techniques I have tried work. I tried calling:

```
link.setAttribute("data-bind", "click: $root.someFunction.bind($param, 'abc')
```

followed by a call to:

```
ko.applyBindings(this, d);
```

But the click binding never fires. I've also tried:

```
ko.applyBindingsToNode(link, { click: function() { console.log('aaaaaaaaa'); } }, this);
```

but again, nothing is triggered. Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Could a solution like this work?  You could have an observable (observableArray) representing the link(s) you want to show.  As you can see below, I delay creating the link model until after binding has already happened (on the button click).  I'm not sure if this is feasible but seems like it could be.  Cheers!

```js
function generateLink(href) {
  var self = this;
  
  self.href = href;
  self.target = "_blank";
  self.textContext = "link";
  
  return self;
}

function ParentViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  
  self.generatedLink = ko.observable(null);
  
  self.onClick = function() {
    self.generatedLink(generateLink('http://google.com'));
  }
  
  return self;
}

ko.applyBindings(new ParentViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<button data-bind="click: onClick">Show</button>

<!-- ko with: generatedLink -->
<div>
  <a data-bind="text: href, attr: {href: href, target: target, textContext: textContext}"></a>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd have to look more into how `applyBindings` processes the nodes to explain exactly why it fails, but it can be done (hackishly).

```js
var vm = {
  someObservable: ko.observable()
}

vm.generateLink= function() {
  var d = document.createElement("div");
  var link = document.createElement("a");
  link.href = "someurl.com";
  link.target = "_blank";
  link.textContent = "link";
  d.appendChild(link);

  link.setAttribute("data-bind", "click: function(){console.log('clicked')}");
  link.setAttribute("id", "myLink");
  
  setTimeout(function(){
    ko.applyBindings({}, document.getElementById('myLink'))},
    1000)
    
  return d.innerHTML;
}

ko.applyBindings(vm)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<input type='checkbox' data-bind='checked: someObservable'>Toggle</input>

<!-- ko with: someObservable -->
<span data-bind="html: $root.generateLink()"></span>
<!-- /ko -->
```

I would highly advise against using said approach. Leveraging the suite of bindings Knockout provides enables you to dispense with the need to make calls against `document`. If you are manually manipulating the structure of the DOM, it defeats the purpose of using Knockout and makes you work harder to achieve results--case in point the issue at hand. The `html` binding isn't the approach I would use in this case. There are several ways to achieve the desired result while maintaining more of a M-V-VM separation.

On a side a note, unless things have changed, using self-closing tags can result in [unexpected behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17448615/binding-multiple-span-tags-with-knockout-inside-a-container-only-rendering-the-f?lq=1).